# How to extract months and year from a timestamp in postgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql

With PostgreSQL, while using the AGE() function to display age from date of birth in my table, with query

```
SELECT date_of_birth, AGE(NOW(), date_of_birth) AS age FROM person;
```

Got the following,[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkA3F.png).

I want to select only year and month from the timestamp, so the result be like "1 year 3 mons",

Tried using EXTRACT(),it outs only one field at a time,

```
SELECT date_of_birth, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM AGE(NOW(), date_of_birth)) AS age FROM person;
```

and, TO_CHAR(),

```
SELECT date_of_birth, TO_CHAR(AGE(NOW(), date_of_birth), 'YY-MM') AS age FROM person;
```

But the result is not in the desired format, can anyone please explain how to use the above methods in correct way or any other methods to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the interval using `TO_CHAR()`:

```
TO_CHAR(AGE(NOW(), date_of_birth), 'YY "Year" MM "month"') AS age
```

However, a more colloquial solution is to build the parts separately:

```
   CONCAT_WS(' ',
             (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v.age) = 0 THEN NULL
                   WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v.age) = 1 THEN '1 year'
                   ELSE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v.age) || ' years'
              END),
             (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.age) = 1 THEN '1 month'
                   ELSE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v.age) || ' months'
              END)
           ) as age
```

This handles things like "1 year" versus "2 years".

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=200a06bffcfcbe34c9cc04bc29d9638c) is a db<>fiddle.